# Como ponerle Doble cero(00) a un NumberPicker

Tags: java, android

Tengo este código y no he podido hacer que en el `NumberPicker` se vea el `00` como lo tengo ahí,  solo se ve el `0` solo.

```
numberPicker.setMaxValue(59);
numberPicker.setMinValue(00);
numberPicker.setValue(3);

btnCalcular.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v){
    if(numberPicker.getValue()<10){
      txtDato.setText("Valor de number "+0+numberPicker.getValue());
    }else{
      txtDato.setText("Valor de number "+numberPicker.getValue());
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar setFormatter para aplicar un formato al number picker.

```
numberPicker.setMaxValue(59);
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker.setValue(3);
numberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
        @Override
        public String format(int i) {
            return String.format("%02d", i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Rcordoval. Estuvo perfecto. Bendiciones para ti.